# Find user by email address using Active directory client library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have found a link to GET users by objectId and principalname.

Ref: 
[Announcing Azure AD Graph API Client Library 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/11/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0/)

I have a use case like, before creating the user in AD I want to check whether the emailaddress is already exist there or not.

I get this exception when the user is already there:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Another object with the same value for property signInNames already exists."},"date":"2018-05-29T06:54:41","requestId":"9ac7e678-7426-4dfd-9aa5-89c24038b9e0","values":[{"item":"PropertyName","value":"signInNames"},{"item":"PropertyErrorCode","value":"ObjectConflict"}]}}
```

So, is there any simple option to check emailaddress existence before creating user?

Got the below exception when trying with answer posted by Martin
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a query to check whether a user with that signin name exists:

```
Client.Users.Where(u => u.SignInNames.Any(x => x.Type == "emailAddress" && x.Value == YourEmail@yourdomain.com)).ExecuteSingleAsync()
```

If you use AAD B2C you have to omit the Type check for the SignInNames.

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion but ended up with an error. ""Filtering on property 'type' is not currently supported."

Comment: Ahh, probably because it aad b2c?

Comment: I answered your new question. Please consider accepting this answer using the green checkmark

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with the query below and it works fine.

```
Client.Users.Where(u => u.SignInNames.Any(x => x.Value == "YourEmail@yourdomain.com")).ExecuteSingleAsync();
```

Thanks @Martin Brandl